# How to make the order of views the same in all languages

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the order of views in my app. When I change the language 
of the system from English to Arabic in my phone the order of views change.

to be more clear here an example.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share your xml file

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line in your manifest
‘android:supportsRtl="false"’

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` in topmost layout in your xml.